# as3 facebook api: are both facebook.init and facebook.login required

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, api

if my app's FacebookDesktop.init succeeds, I seem to be able to avoid the FacebookDesktop.login step.

is this a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, init just initializes the API while login will log the user in to Facebook and authorize the app. If you're already logged in to FB, but have not authorized the app, then login will still be necessary. I think the standard process is to check login status using [Facebook.getLoginStatus()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) after you initialize the app.

The login status result will give you `connected` (user is logged in and has authorized your app), `not_authorized` (user is logged in but has not authorized your app), and `unknown` (user is not logged in).

Comment: please note: Facebook.getLoginStatus **REQUIRES** a custom eventlistener to get that response ... the as3-fb-api documentation does not make this obvious: _...You **can** listen for..._ as if I have an option. It should read: _...You **must** listen for..._. [as3-fb-api docs](http://facebook-actionscript-api.googlecode.com/svn/release/current/docs/index.html)